# ExecuteScalar() analogue in custom Linq to Sql query

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I need to execute a custom sql query that i cannot do with regular L2S means:

```
select [row_number] from (select row_number() over (order by CreatedOn desc, ID desc) as [row_number], ID from MyTable) as T1 where ID = {0}
```

so i'm trying

```
var r = db.ExecuteQuery<int>(q, id).Single();
```

but that doesn't work (getting System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
var r = db.ExecuteQuery<long>(q, id).Single();
```

by changing the return type from `System.Int32`(`int`) to `System.Int64` (`long`).

T-SQL function [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) return type is `bigint`, not `int` as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

you may try changing your code from

```
int recordsAffected = SqlDBUtils.GetInt(dr, "SerialNumber");
```

to

```
int recordsAffected = SqlDBUtils.GetInt64(dr, "SerialNumber");
```

Because `ROW_NUMBER()` function in SQL returns `BigInt` instead of Int